# CS0123 C# No overload for 'HyperlinkButtonClick' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler'

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, delegates

Windows universal app. I didn't find answer here. I got a mistake **CS0123  C# No overload for 'HyperlinkButtonClick' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler'**. Most of answers on same questions tells to watch signature more carefully. Or to use more "`global`" because I've got windows-named namespace. But in my case (I think) the case is in something else. I just want to get from one page to another. It looks like problem in autogenerated file, but it shouldn't be so. Second page is in the same namespace. Help me, please :)

Sample of code:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="somepath.Windows.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:somepath.Windows"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel x:Name="contentPanel" Margin="8,32,0,0">
           <HyperlinkButton x:Name="nameButton" Content="name" Click="HyperlinkButtonClick" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace somepath.Windows
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void HyperlinkButtonClick (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate (typeof (SecondPage));
        }
    }
}
```

And there's an auto generated file

**MainPage.g.cs**

```
       namespace somepath.Windows
    {
        partial class MainPage : 
            global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page, 
            global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector,
            global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector2
        {
                      [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks"," 14.0.0.0")]
            [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
            public void Connect(int connectionId, object target)
            {
                switch(connectionId)
                {
                case 1:
                   .
                   .
                   .
                case 15:
                    {
                        this.nameButton = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.HyperlinkButton)(target);
                        #line 25 "..\..\..\MainPage.xaml"


((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.HyperlinkButton)this.nameButton).Click += this.HyperlinkButtonClick;

                        #line default
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                this._contentLoaded = true;
            }

            [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks"," 14.0.0.0")]
            [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
            public global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector GetBindingConnector(int connectionId, object target)
            {
                global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector returnValue = null;
                return returnValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handler in MainPage.xaml.cs is incorrect. The second parameter should be of type **RoutedEventArgs, not System.EventArgs.**

So, change the following code:

```
    private void HyperlinkButtonClick (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate (typeof (SecondPage));
    }
```

To this:

```
    private void HyperlinkButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate (typeof (SecondPage));
    }
```